# emacs: run grep process without looking for .cshrc file in home directory

Tags: linux, emacs, grep

When I run emacs commands like `grep` or `rgrep` a new shell process is started and .cshrc is loaded from the home directory. There is quite a lot of stuff in it and I don't want to load it every time simply search for something.

So, my question is how to run grep without loading .cshrc file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a nice workaround: add this line at the very beginning of .cshrc file

```
if ("$TERM" == "emacs-grep") exit
```